# How to get icon for network computer ( smb/afp ) on macOS based on type

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is it possible to get icon for network computer/ip address under macOS so iMac has iMac icon etc?

I am using `NSNetServiceBrowser` to get available services, but I do not know how to get icon like official Finder app does. Finder recognize icons for iMac, MacBookPro etc. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how Finder does it, but one explanation would be Finder can map a MAC address to a device type. But this information is only available to Apple.

Comment: I have already investigate posibility to get type from MAC address, but it looks complicated. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50678 I was hoping that some "hidden" api can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a working solution for you, but I see your question didn't get much attention yet so maybe I can point you in the right direction.

Finder looks for services, and it will check if found services have "device info" associated with them. This is done via Bonjour, looking for a _device-info._tcp pseudo service. A lookup for a device info may return a Bonjour TXT record that indicates the model ID of the gizmo. If Finder succeeds in getting this info, then it assigns an icon accordingly, otherwise, it picks a generic icon.

The icons themselves seem to be stored here: `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle` (at least on my 10.13 machine). Check the Info.plist on that bundle, and the other bundles contained within, and you can find mappings between device types and icons.

There are some posts talking about how to customise the icon that's shown for certain devices:

[Add custom network device icons in Mac OS X Finder?](https://superuser.com/questions/364683/add-custom-network-device-icons-in-mac-os-x-finder)

[Can you use Bonjour for Windows to broadcast a different icon than the Bluescreen?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3131124?start=0&tstart=0)

I tried to follow the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309740/how-do-i-obtain-model-name-for-a-networked-device-potentially-using-bonjour) to examine the model names advertised by some Apple hardware on my network, but couldn't make it work (either using the `dig` tool or with `NSNetService`) (although I admit I didn't try very hard with `NSNetService` as I'm not familiar with it).

[This thread](https://lists.apple.com/archives/bonjour-dev/2011/Jul/msg00016.html) discusses potential problems and solutions, however the `dig` tool wouldn't work for me despite having both SMB and AFP over TCP enabled.

All of these threads are fairly old, although the commentary in the linked SO post suggest this still works at least as of Sierra.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunatelly I did not look up old answer about _device-info._tcp what a shame.